# onClick Function Only Works On First Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a function for on each click loads a subset of photos using imagepicker. I know all of the functions work independently, but to get them to work with image picker I made one larger compiled function. The function works but only on the first click. I can't seem to address why this is happening. Can someone point out where and why this is happening? Thanks.

```
var feature_lst = new Array("oder", "gill_size", "spore_print_color", "habitat");

var min = 0;

function onClick(json_lst, min){
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oder = {
        images : ["odor_almond.jpeg", "odor_anise.jpeg", "odor_creosote.jpg", "odor_fishy.jpg", "odor_foul.jpg", "odor_musty.jpeg", "odor_none.jpeg", "odor_pungent.jpg", "odor_spicy .jpg"],
        values : ["a", "l", "c", "y", "f", "m", "n", "p", "s"],
        text : ["Almond", "Anise", "Creosote", "Fishy", "Foul", "Musty", "None", "Pungent", "Spicy"]
    };

    var gill_size = {
        images : ["broad_gillsize.jpeg", "narrow_gillsize.jpeg"],
        values : ["b", "n"],
        text : ["Broad gill-size", "Narrow gill-size"]
    };

    var spore_print_color = {
        images : ["spc_black.jpg","spc_brown.jpg", "spc_buff.jpg", "spc_chocolate.jpeg", "spc_green.png", "spc_orange.jpeg", "spc_purple.jpeg", "spc_white.jpeg", "spc_yellow.jpg"],
        values : ["k", "n", "b", "h", "r", "o", "u", "w", "y"],
        text : ["Black", "Brown", "Buff", "Chocolate", "Green", "Orange", "Purple", "White", "Yellow"]
    };

    var habitat = {
        images : ["hab_grasses.jpeg", "hab_leaves.jpeg", "hab_meadow.jpg", "hab_path.jpg", "hab_urban.jpg", "hab_waste.jpeg", "hab_woods.jpg"],
        values : ["g", "l", "m", "p", "u", "w", "d"],
        text : ["Grasses", "Leaves", "Meadows", "Paths", "Urban", "Waste", "Woods"]
    };

    var container = []

    $("select").imagepicker({
        clicked:function(){
            //Sends image value
            var value = this.val();
            container.push(value);
            //Remove Options
            document.getElementsByClassName('picker')[0].options.length = 0
            //Adds New Options
            var max = json_lst.length - 1, select = document.getElementsByClassName('picker')[0]

            if(min <= max){
                console.log(min)
                for (i = 0; i <= eval(eval(json_lst)[min]).images.length - 1; i++){
                    var opt = document.createElement("option");
                    opt.setAttribute('value', eval(json_lst[min]).values[i]);
                    opt.setAttribute('data-img-src', '../static/feature_imgs/' + eval(json_lst[min]).images[i]);
                    opt.setAttribute('innerHTML', eval(json_lst[min]).text[i]);
                    select.appendChild(opt);

                                }
                            $('select').imagepicker();
                            min = min + 1
                            console.log(min)
                            return min
                            }
                else {
                    alert("You have made a selection for each parameter. Please hit the submit button. ");
                    }

            }
        });
    });
}
```

I call the function in a `<script>` tag

```
onClick(feature_lst, min);
```

Comment: Does your console output any errors?

Comment: Why do you reinitialize the plugin in every iteration of the loop again and not pass in any options?

Comment: Please delete this line $(document).ready(function(){ and closed curly  and read about ready event

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ why? You don't know if all this code is in the head or not

Comment: any live url where you are working on this code?

Comment: Try wrapping your onClick function inside document.ready instead.

Comment: @Zak the console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @charlietfl in order to update the changes the option I have to reinitialize the plugin.  Check out the [documentation](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/)

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ why do I need to delete that statement?

Comment: But you have no `clicked` option when you do that and makes no sense doing it in every iteration of the loop

Comment: @charlietfl oh I see what you are saying now. Its not that way in my file, let me update it.

Comment: OK..that takes care of the loop but you still don't have a `clicked` option when you initialize it again

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. Any way you could give an example of how that would work? `$('select').imagepicker(clicked:onClick{})`

Comment: Please apply @Charlie Weems answer you use wrong place ready and click